# .NET 6: The best way to run a query after opening the site as a lifetime

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-6.0, lifetime

I wrote a middleware in `program.cs` and I want some information to be deleted from the database when the site is launched.

It works well at localhost and the query is executed and the data is deleted, but when I publish it, it displays a 503 error on the server after a few minutes, and when I delete it, the 503 error handler is not displayed and the site works fine.

Middleware code in `Program.cs`:

```
IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime = app.Lifetime;

static async void AddLogs(IApplicationBuilder app){

using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())      
{
    var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<DBContext>();
    
    DateTime dateNow = DateTime.ParseExact(DateConvertor.ToShamsi(), "yyyy/MM/dd", null);

    bool ExistRememberNow = context.HistoryReserves.AsEnumerable().Any(h => DateTime.ParseExact(h.RemmberDate.ToString(), "yyyy/MM/dd", null) == dateNow);

    if (ExistRememberNow)
    {
       var ExistHistoryDateNow = context.HistoryReserves.Include(u => u.User).ThenInclude(u => u.UserDetail).AsEnumerable().Where(h => DateTime.ParseExact(h.RemmberDate, "yyyy/MM/dd", null) == dateNow).ToList();
        foreach (var user in ExistHistoryDateNow)
        {
           string message = "Sen Text Message";
           SmsSender.VerifySend(user.User.Mobile, message);
        }

        context.HistoryReserves.RemoveRange(ExistHistoryDateNow);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    string timeNow = DateConvertor.GetShamsiTime();
    var reserveUsers = context.ReserveTimes
                              .Include(r => r.ReserveDate)
                              .AsEnumerable()
                              .Where(r => DateTime.ParseExact(r.ReserveDate.DateReserve, "yyyy/MM/dd", null) == dateNow
                                          && TimeSpan.Parse(r.EndTimeReserve, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) < TimeSpan.Parse(timeNow, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                              .FirstOrDefault();
    if (reserveUsers != null)
    {
       var deleteReserveTime = context.ReserveTimes.Find(reserveUsers.Id);
       context.ReserveTimes.Remove(deleteReserveTime);
       context.SaveChanges();
   }

   var pastDate = context.ReserveDates.AsEnumerable().Where(r => DateTime.ParseExact(r.DateReserve, "yyyy/MM/dd", null) < DateTime.Now).ToList();

   if (pastDate.Count() != 0)
   {
        context.RemoveRange(pastDate);
        context.SaveChanges();
   }

   lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => AddLogs(app));

   app.UseHttpsRedirection();
   app.UseStaticFiles();
}
```

I thought the problem was with the host server, but I changed the host, but it was still the problem.

What is the best way to run the code as a lifetime, which will run well and without problems on the server?

Comment: 503 wont help much to determine the problem. The real error would be much more useful here.

Comment: @jebWhen I delete Middleware, there is no problem. I checked a lot. I think it's because of this

Comment: i am not questioning that the error might be related to this code, i am just saying the real error would be much more useful to determine the problem.

Comment: I would check for null before calling .toList().  It'll also be easier to manage if you put this in a "seed" class and then call it.